# Error while parsing xml file

Tags: android, xml-parsing

my app needs to download a rss file in xml.  i parse the data but i don't able to insert them into listview.

my code is.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    ProgressDialog progress =null;
    private final static String ADDRESS ="http://www.repubblica.it/rss/sport/rss2.0.xml";
    private ListView lista =null ;
    private List<ArticleInfo> list = null;
   private  ArrayAdapter<ArticleInfo> adapter = null ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //adapter =new ArrayAdapter<ArticleInfo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
       //lista.setAdapter(adapter);





        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMax(100);
        progress.setMessage("Attendi qualche istante");



}

        public void start(View v){

            new BackgroundTask().execute();
        }



       private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {


           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

               URL url = null;
               try {
                   url = new URL(ADDRESS);
               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   return null;
               }
               StringBuffer buffer=null;
               try {
                   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                   String tmp = null;
                   buffer = new StringBuffer();
                   while((tmp=reader.readLine())!= null){
                       buffer.append(tmp);

                   }
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   return null;
               }
              list = RssParser.parseXML(buffer.toString());

               return buffer.toString();

           }
           @Override
           protected  void onPreExecute(){

               progress.setProgress(0);
               progress.show();

           }
           @Override
           protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer ... values){

               super.onProgressUpdate(values);
               progress.setProgress(values[0]);
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String res){
            super.onPostExecute(res);
               progress.dismiss();
               if (res!=null){
                      // TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
                        //text.setText(res);
                  adapter =new ArrayAdapter<ArticleInfo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,res);
                   lista.setAdapter(adapter);  **THIS IS MY ERROR** 

               }

           }



       }


   }
```

this is my parser class

```
public class RssParser {

public static List<ArticleInfo> parseXML(String rss){

        List<ArticleInfo> res =new ArrayList<>();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder =null;

try {
    builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { }

try {
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(rss)));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();// aggiungo getDocumentElement()
    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for(int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){

        Node n=list.item(i);
        if(n.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Element e= (Element) n;
            String title = e.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
            String url = e.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).getTextContent();
            res.add(new ArticleInfo(title,url));
        }
    }
} catch (SAXException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {

}

return res;
```

}

the framework gives me an error in the last row of main activity  where i try to crate the adapter

Could you give me an hand ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error you're receiving and on what line? can you provide the xml file that is failing to parse?  Are you getting successful parses at all, or just  failing on one particular file?

Comment: in the last row , i try to create an adapter. i have an error in this part of code adapter =new ArrayAdapter<ArticleInfo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,res);
                   lista.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: `adapter =new ArrayAdapter<ArticleInfo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);` can You try this this will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due of this line

```
adapter =new ArrayAdapter<ArticleInfo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,res);
```

your `ArrayAdapter` is expecting a Collection of `ArticleInfo`, but you are passing `res` which is one single `String`. Change your AsyncTask in order to make it return list instead of `buffer.toString()`, E.g.

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,List<ArticleInfo>>
```

and `doInBackground` returns `list` instead of `buffer.toString()`

Comment: in the RssParser.class res is an List<ArticleInfo> object .

Comment: Listen, your `AsyncTask` is returning a `String`. You can call it as you like, but this doesn't change the fact that it is a `String`.

Comment: right , i have changed following your hints , but the error doesn't desappear .

Comment: there is a problem in the constructor of adapter .

Comment: i have changed the constructor putting context instead this. the error desappears but when i fire the emulator i have a log error like this. at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
            at artetecapp.ilfattounofficial.MainActivity$BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:123)

Comment: Use `MainActivity.this` inside of `this` or `context`.  You should check also it the ArrayList is not null

Comment: ok i used MainActivity instead the context. the adapter finally works. unfortunately, it seems not able to parse.

Comment: when i launch the emulator , the adapter give me strange reference like this. artcleinfo@b30e0a090  etc etc

Comment: Do i have to use two different textviews in the adapter  ?

Comment: last question, if i woud like to insert any image from xml file ? could you suggest me a valid tutorial ?

Comment: for the images i have to modify the asynctask ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i used the context and the error desappear . when i launch the emulator , when the asynctask works, the app goes in crash. the logcat is j

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
            at artetecapp.ilfattounofficial.MainActivity$BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:123)
            at artetecapp.ilfattounofficial.MainActivity$BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:73)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
```

Comment: please edit your original question with the additional information, this should not be posted as an answer.